# Extract values from text files and write to a single spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel

Given a folder containing about 1,200 text files that are all formatted this way...

---

```
Time range of SELECTION
   From 1.133071 to 4.457098 seconds (duration: 3.324027 seconds)
Pitch:
   Median pitch: 172.651 Hz
   Mean pitch: 167.584 Hz
   Standard deviation: 48.839 Hz
   Minimum pitch: 59.460 Hz
   Maximum pitch: 269.304 Hz
Pulses:
   Number of pulses: 216
   Number of periods: 141
   Mean period: 6.646523E-3 seconds
   Standard deviation of period: 2.969047E-3 seconds
Voicing:
   Fraction of locally unvoiced frames: 46.348%   (368 / 794)
   Number of voice breaks: 13
   Degree of voice breaks: 50.270%   (1.670989 seconds / 3.324027 seconds)
Jitter:
   Jitter (local): 5.795%
   Jitter (local, absolute): 385.185E-6 seconds
   Jitter (rap): 2.361%
   Jitter (ppq5): 1.908%
   Jitter (ddp): 7.083%
Shimmer:
   Shimmer (local): 20.262%
   Shimmer (local, dB): 1.841 dB
   Shimmer (apq3): 10.382%
   Shimmer (apq5): 22.335%
   Shimmer (apq11): --undefined--
   Shimmer (dda): 31.145%
Harmonicity of the voiced parts only:
   Mean autocorrelation: 0.515841
   Mean noise-to-harmonics ratio: 1.232685
   Mean harmonics-to-noise ratio: 0.331 dB
```

---

...how might I write some kind of program that goes through all 1,200 of these files, extracts the numerical values only after the strings "duration:", "Mean pitch:", "Minimum pitch:", "Maximum pitch:", "Jitter (local):", "Jitter (rap):", "Shimmer (local):", "Mean noise-to-harmonics ratio:", and "Mean harmonics-to-noise ratio:" and writes them to one big file (that I can open in or paste into Excel) which contains one row of values per text file?

I have found similar problems discussed in these forums that have been solved using Python, but I am having trouble sorting out how all the code works.  I am not very good at that sort of thing.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Post some code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: what's your environment? I have written something similar as an awk script. So if you are using linux/unix/cygwin, it can be done easily. Depending on the your preferences, you can write that in every programming and scripting language. I might be even able to write it as a windows batch script, which might be just a pain in the butt. YMMV

Comment: I am running Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit off-topic; generally, you should come here once you've tried something and run into problems. However:

1. To work through all the files in a folder structure, look into [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).
2. To access the files, read about [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) and [file objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects).
3. To process each line, use [string methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).
4. To export to *.csv, which can easily be opened and further processed in Excel, try the [`csv` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: Best not to point the `string` module for "operations"... They're mostly on the `str` class itself now. The module should really be for constants and base classes... (which shouldn't really be required)

Comment: Pretty neat answer for an off-topic question. +1